# Use XPath to get all nodes until type of first node is encountered again

Tags: php, xpath

I have some third party XML which looks something like this:

```
<body>
  <text>Unimportant Introduction</text>
  <text class="heading">Important Section 1</text>
  <text>Important text</text>
  <table>(Table data)</table>
  <text>Other important text</text>
  <text class="heading">Important Section 2</text>
  <text class="heading"></text>
  <text>Important text</text>
  <text>Other important text</text>
  <text class="heading">Important Section 3</text>
  <text>Important text</text>
  <table>(Table data)</table>
</body>
```

What I want is all the nodes from a non-empty `<text class="heading">` onwards but stopping just before another non-empty `<text class="heading">`. It's important that the last `<text class="heading">` captures the remaining nodes within `<body>`, so something like this (doesn't have to be exact):

```
array(
  0 => DOMNodeList {
    <text class="heading">Important Section 1</text>
    <text>Important text</text>
    <table>(Table data)</table>
    <text>Other important text</text>
  },
  1 => DOMNodeList {
    <text class="heading">Important Section 2</text>
    <text class="heading"></text>
    <text>Important text</text>
    <text>Other important text</text>
  },
  2 => DOMNodeList {
    <text class="heading">Important Section 3</text>
    <text>Important text</text>
    <table>(Table data)</table>
  }
)
```

If I can't do this (separating and grouping children) in a single XPath, then looping is OK too.

I can already find just the `<text class="heading">` nodes with `//body/text[@class=\'heading\' and string-length(text()) > 0]` but I don't know how to add all the siblings in.

Edit:

I just realised that what I really want is more like this:

```
array(
  0 => DOMElement {
    <body>
      <text class="heading">Important Section 1</text>
      <text>Important text</text>
      <table>(Table data)</table>
      <text>Other important text</text>
    </body>
  },
  1 => DOMElement {
    <body>
      <text class="heading">Important Section 2</text>
      <text class="heading"></text>
      <text>Important text</text>
      <text>Other important text</text>
    </body>
  },
  2 => DOMElement {
    <body>
      <text class="heading">Important Section 3</text>
      <text>Important text</text>
      <table>(Table data)</table>
    </body>
  }
)
```

Having all the required nodes inside the `<body>` node would be really useful!

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what I want in a loop:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOT
<body>
  <text>Unimportant Introduction</text>
  <text class="heading">Important Section 1</text>
  <text>Important text 1</text>
  <table>(Table data) 1</table>
  <text>Other important text 1</text>
  <text class="heading">Important Section 2</text>
  <text class="heading"></text>
  <text>Important text 2</text>
  <text>Other important text 2</text>
  <text class="heading">Important Section 3</text>
  <text>Important text 3</text>
  <table>(Table data) 3</table>
</body>
EOT;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$heading = "text[@class='heading' and string-length(text()) > 0]";
$nodes = $finder->query("//body/{$heading}");
$num_sections = $nodes->length;

for ($num = 1; $num <= $num_sections; ++$num) {
  // Find all nodes that match the nth heading or any nodes after the nth heading
  // (nth heading plus all following nodes)
  $node_set1 = "(//body/{$heading}[{$num}] | //body/{$heading}[{$num}]/following-sibling::*)";
  // Find the next heading after the nth heading (if it exists) or any nodes after that
  // (n+1-th heading plus all following nodes)
  $node_set2 = "//body/{$heading}[{$num}]/following-sibling::{$heading}[1] | //body/{$heading}[{$num}]/following-sibling::{$heading}[1]/following-sibling::*";

  // Find all nodes that are in the first set but not in the second set
  $nodes = $finder->query("{$node_set1}[count(.| {$node_set2})!=count({$node_set2})]");

  print("Section $num:<br/>\n");
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sx = simplexml_import_dom($node);
    var_dump($sx->asXML());
  }
}
?>
```

It outputs (with Xdebug):

```
Section 1:
string '<text class="heading">Important Section 1</text>' (length=48)
string '<text>Important text 1</text>' (length=29)
string '<table>(Table data) 1</table>' (length=29)
string '<text>Other important text 1</text>' (length=35)
Section 2:
string '<text class="heading">Important Section 2</text>' (length=48)
string '<text class="heading"/>' (length=23)
string '<text>Important text 2</text>' (length=29)
string '<text>Other important text 2</text>' (length=35)
Section 3:
string '<text class="heading">Important Section 3</text>' (length=48)
string '<text>Important text 3</text>' (length=29)
string '<table>(Table data) 3</table>' (length=29)
```

I don't know if this is the simplest solution but it does the trick!

Comment: Well, it turns out that XPath is so slow when working with over 50 000 second level nodes that I ended up using the DOM libraries instead. Now it finishes in about 9 seconds instead of over an hour!